# Replaced keyboard now acting strangely

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, keyboard-layout, hardware

I purchased a new keyboard for my Lenovo thinkpad laptop after spilling liquid on it, causing half the keys not to respond. It is running Ubuntu 16.04, and there are some strange things happening with it.

- End key no longer goes to the end of a line, but the end of a
  document. Same for home. Page also scrolls.
- Repeating keys by keeping them depressed works for all apart from the left arrow.
- Up arrow only works if pressed hard (nothing seems to be blocking it, I removed and
  reinstalled it, same issue).

The new keyboard is a US layout, and I had a UK one previously, are there some configurations in Ubuntu I could play with? I tried `Keyboard > Input sources` and I couldn't see any change that would help.

Is there anything left to diagnose or is it definitely faulty?

Comment: Start with setting the keyboard layout that matches your new one.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: I just set it to US, it doesnt seem to have made a difference

Comment: I managed to set it to US, which means at least the keys are mapped correctly, but i still have the other issues

Comment: The other issues are very likely hardware related. We cannot help you with that.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: Ehh.. Yes, there are most likely people at Ask Ubuntu who can help with that. I made an attempt to help in an answer.

Comment: Thank you for that, I knew it was likely hardware but wanted to know how to diagnose better, your answer helped

Answer (score 1):

Besides the keyboard layout, the XKB keyboard configuration also lets you set a keyboard model value which matches your physical keyboard.

Open a terminal window and run this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

It opens a dialogue, and the first thing you are prompted to select is the model. The currently selected model does probably not fit your new keyboard.